# Overlapping bubbles and System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Tags: c#, charts, data-visualization

We have a legacy application that is built using C# System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.  We've been asked to create a graph that shows a series of bubble points floating at the same y distance above a horizontal line, scattered left to right based on their values. So far, no problem. However, the next requirement has me a bit stumped. Where two bubbles overlap, they would like the overlapping region to be shaded darker, essentially summing the two colors. Like a Venn diagram but with several dozen data points.

Does anyone know if there is a simple setting we can use to do this?  If not, I might have to tell them that its a) not possible with this tool set or b) the best I can do is to increase the shading on an entire bubble when there are multiple data points with the same (or within a range) value.

Comment: You could use transparency on the colouring